# React Sliding up panel for web

Tags: reactjs

do you know if there is a component like this one
https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel but for a react web app?

I searched a lot on the web, I am also looking for a old-fashioned javascript component to adapt... let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I also use `rn-sliding-up-panel` in my react native app.

You can use [PEP jQuery](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) or [hammerjs plugins](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for web.